# Can't copy article content from community articles

Tags: customer-community, articles

Our community users can't copy & paste articles content (We are using Napili template) from the community.
Has anyone encountered this issue?
Is there an option to allow article copy from the community?
You can see a screen shot of a community page. You can't copy any of the info on that page or any other page.

[image: Community screen shot]

Comment: They can't copy the text from articles? It might be helpful if you could post a screenshot